# Authentication error when using BigqueryService

Tags: c#, google-bigquery

I'm trying to connect to my BigQuery project and grab a list of datasets using a BigqueryService instance. I am able to do this successfully using a BigQueryClient; however, I have a requirement to use a BigqueryService. What am I missing?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    GoogleCredential credential;
    BigqueryService service;

    string query;

    using (var json = new FileStream("secretkey.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(json);

        service = new BigqueryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
        {
            ApplicationName = "BigQueryTest",
            HttpClientInitializer = credential
        });
    }

    try
    {
        var serviceList = service.Datasets.List("testproject").Execute();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

    var client = BigQueryClient.Create("testproject", credential);
    var clientList = client.ListDatasets();

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

On running, I hit an exception saying "Request has invalid authentication credentials..." for Service.Datasets.List(), but the client.ListDatasets() runs without issue.

Edit:
I solved the issue. I needed to use GoogleCredential.CreateScoped() to create my credentials. The working code:

```
credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(json);
            string[] scopes = new string[] { BigqueryService.Scope.Bigquery 
};
credential = credential.CreateScoped(scopes);

service = new BigqueryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
{
    ApplicationName = "BigQueryTest",
    HttpClientInitializer = credential
});
```